# What is the english meaning of this shloka? Draupadyaa damantyaa cha savitryaa susheelayaa- Duritaani jitaanyeetajjapaadaaptam cha vanchitam

Tags: translation-request, stotra, meaning

> “Draupadyaa damantyaa cha savitryaa susheelayaa- Duritaani jitaanyeetajjapaadaaptam cha vanchitam.”

Its from sri krishna saharanama stotram.

And also i found another shloka similar to it.

> द्रौपदी दमयंती चाय सावित्री सुशीलिया - दुरीतां जीतनजितजपदपटम: चाय वंचितं

Can you please give english meaning to it also and please let me know the source of this shloka too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verse you are looking for is the following:-

> द्रौपद्या दमयन्त्या च सावित्र्या च सुशीलया ।
> दुरितानि जितान्येतज्जपादाप्तं च वाञ्छितम् ॥

It is from the फलश्रुति (Phalashruti) of the Sri Krishna Sahasranama Stotram. A phalashruti of any set of verses indicates the benefits of studying, reciting, memorising and practising the verses regularly. So let us see what this particular verse means.

The first line consists of four names- Draupadi, Damayanti, Savitri and Susheela. These are four strong ladies from various mythological stories of India. They all were known for their devotion, persistence and honesty.

The second line begins with the word दुरितानि (Duritaani). The word दुरित (Durita) in Sanskrit is used to denote “suffering, bad time, sin, danger, discomfort, difficulties etc”. So दुरितानि would mean sufferings here.

Next word is जितानि (Jitaani). जित (Jita) means “won, defeated, overcome etc”. Here, the plural of the same is used because this is indicating multiple difficulties faced by the women discussed above. So it means “the difficulties of Draupadi, Damayanti, Savitri and Susheela were overcome”.

Now the next words indicate how the difficulties were overcome. एतत् जपात् (Etat japaat). एतत् means “this”. The word जप (Japa) means chanting, memorizing etc. So एतत् जपात् means “by chanting this”. The word “this” here indicates the Sri Krishna Sahasranama Stotram.

The next words are a bit tricky. आप्तं च वाञ्छितम् (Aaptam cha vaanchhitam) can mean many things as आप्तं and वाञ्छितम् have multiple meanings. But the only meanings for both the words that fit here together perfectly are “received” and “desired” respectively. So it can be inferred as “they also received what they desired”.

Now let us collect the meaning of all the words and translate the full verse.

> द्रौपद्या दमयन्त्या च सावित्र्या च सुशीलया ।
> दुरितानि जितान्येतज्जपादाप्तं च वाञ्छितम् ॥

By chanting this (Stotram), sufferings of Draupadi, Damayanti, Savitri and Susheela were overcome and they received what they desired.

CREDIT GOES TO VISHNU ELAYATH FROM QUORA FOR ANSWERING THE QUESTION.